# Is it possible to not place an servlet filter into service?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Based on java ee 5 api:
The web container cannot place the filter into service if the init method either
1.Throws a ServletException 
2.Does not return within a time period defined by the web container

What I have done is to throw an ServletException when any part of the work in the init method failed.
However, what I have observed is that the web container starts but all of the requests will return with 404 error. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the behaviour you expect - container shutdown?

Comment: @home no. in stead, the web app should still work without calling that filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the logic for this is that a filter is an integral part of the handling of a request; if a part fails, the entire request fails. Therefore a filter that fails to init is considered unable to serve, so any request that would normally pass through it will fail.

If a filter is optional for your case, then I would suggest a logic as (almost pseudocode):

```
private boolean canServe = false;

public void init(FilterConfig fc) {
    if( filter activation condition ) {
        canServe = true;
    }
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    if( canServe ) {
        // filter logic - filter is ON
    }
    else chain.doFilter(request, response); // filter is OFF
}
```

Alternatively, if the filter availability can be configured at compile time (e.g. environment based - DEV, STAGING, PRODUCTION), a conditional build (e.g. Ant) that will remove the filter definition from web.xml could be employed.